# Using logical operators to conditionally enable/disable button element

Tags: javascript, reactjs, button

Fairly new to ReactJS. Have searched for a similar topic to no avail. On my app, I want to only enable my submit button if all fields have content. All input fields are bound to state.

On my onChange event handler function:

- I update states bound to my fields, thereby updating my input fields
- In the same handler function, I declare a boolean based on a logical operator chain of every state that needs a value using '&&'
- Assign the !result to a state named 'buttonDisabled'
- This state is then assigned to the 'disabled' property of button
- Default state of disabled property is true

Code

```
onInputChange = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const newValue = e.target.value;

    const targetElement = e.target.id;
    this.setState(() => {

        return {
            entryInput: newValue, 
            [targetElement]: newValue
        }
    })

    this.setState( () => {
        let buttonState =
        (this.state.symbol && 
        this.state.contracts &&
        this.state.open);
        return {
            buttonDisabled: buttonState
        }

    })

}
```

On my button element:

```
<Button disabled={this.state.buttonDisabled} onClick={...} ?>
```

Expected result - 'Submit' is disabled until the moment all states contain values (i.e. all fields have values)

Actual result - 'Submit' is disabled, but enables on the second entry of the last text box I fill out.

- I've console logged the resulting boolean and it matches exact conditions
- The button enable/disable seems to be an update behind
- Thinking it might be how && returns boolean/values, I explicitly used comparisons to === '' and same issue. Have also tried a if/else statement

I probably have a logic gap here somewhere, but have been spinning my wheels for a bit and would be great to get a bit of help.

thanks

Comment: The reason it's one update behind is because setState does not immediately update the state but it creates a state transition. I would put these in the render method and then use that for the comparison

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to store the value in the state, you can actually do the checking in the *render* function itself. By **default** the *render* function is called every time *setState* is called:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

class Form extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      name: "",
      age: ""
    };
  }

  nameChange = (e) => {
    this.setState({ name: e.target.value });
  };

  ageChange = (e) => {
    this.setState({ age: e.target.value });
  };

  submit = () => {
    const { name, age } = this.state;
    alert(`name: ${name} is age: ${age}`);
  };

  render() {
    const { name, age } = this.state;
    const enabled = name.length > 0 && age.length > 0;
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.submit}>
        <input
          type="text"
          placeholder="Enter name"
          value={this.state.name}
          onChange={this.nameChange}
        />
        <input
          type="text"
          placeholder="Enter age"
          value={this.state.age}
          onChange={this.ageChange}
        />
        <button disabled={!enabled}>Submit</button>
      </form>
    );
  }
}

const root = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<Form />, root);
```

Also, keep in mind:

> setState() does not immediately mutate this.state but creates a
>   pending state transition. Accessing this.state after calling this
>   method can potentially return the existing value. There is no
>   guarantee of synchronous operation of calls to setState and calls may
>   be batched for performance gains.

Comment: Thanks! Putting the logic in render() did it. Looks like I have some reading to do on the setState function.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to change the second setState so that you accept state as an input parameter:

```
this.setState((newState) => {
    let buttonState =
    (newState.symbol && 
    newState.contracts &&
    newState.open);
    return {
        buttonDisabled: buttonState
    }
})
```

In general if you are using state inside the setState `updater` fn, you need to use the state that is passed as a parameter to the `updater` as opposed to `this.state`.

I believe this is because calls to setState are not guaranteed to be immediate, and in cases of multiple calls they can be queued and applied in batched. In other words in your case the updates are only applied to `this.state` after fns have run, so if you are relying on this.state then the second setState `updater` fn will not see the effect of the first setState `updater` fn. If the second fn needs access to the result of the first, then you need to use the provided intermediate state value.

This is explained much better in the "Passing a Function to setState()" section this tutorial : https://css-tricks.com/understanding-react-setstate/#article-header-id-1

As well as in the official docs here : https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate . This quote from the docs is key:

> Think of setState() as a request rather than an immediate command to update the component. For better perceived performance, React may delay it, and then update several components in a single pass. React does not guarantee that the state changes are applied immediately.

Hope this helps.